# not entering in "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {"

Tags: javascript

I am following my old question post that I suddenly enter in a new problem that is: my code is not entering in this line "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()". I also checked by marking alert. so I unable to understand. can somebody tell me why this is not happening?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function changeThis(){

                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value; 
                /* formInput will be undefined */
               document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
               /* also undefined */
               //    var xmlHttp = null;

               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() //help
               {
                   alert("y"); // not entering help?????
                   if (xmlhttp.readystate==4 && http.status==200)
                   {
                       document.getElemenById('newText').innerHTML=xmlhttp.reponseText;
                   }
                   if(xmlhttp.status == 404)
                   {
                       var temp = "NO file found";
                       document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML=temp;
                   }
                   xmlHttp.open( "GET", "file2.php", true);
                   xmlHttp.send();   
             }
         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p> 
     <textarea id="theInput" style="height:200px;">Write Here</textarea>
     <input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='See what you wrote'/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

```
                   xmlHttp.open( "GET", "file2.php", true);
                   xmlHttp.send();
```

outside of the `onreadystatechange` handler; your current code won't try to submit the HTTP request until after the HTTP request is already making progress. (Hat-tip to [judder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643653/judder) for editing your question to indent your code properly, making this problem obvious.)

**Edited to add:** Also, as [Pavlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092711/pavlo) points out, you need to consistently write `xmlHttp`. JavaScript variable-names are case-sensitive, so `xmlhttp` is a completely different variable.

Comment: i did this but no parameter is entering inside the  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function . if u could see my comments in code you would probably understand what i am asking and may be you could find where i am doing wrong.

Comment: @user3162878 also, mind the capitalisation. JavaScript variables are case-sensitive, so `xmlhttp` is not the same as `xmlHttp`.

Comment: where shell i apply your suggestions? is it like this xmlhttp.open(....) instead of  xmlHttp.open( "GET", "file2.php", true); and xmlHttp.send(); ????